# How to show specific information depended on user-input?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am working with Wordpress and the Woocommerce plugin. There, at the checkout-page I would like to show specific information depended on what the user does write into a input-field. I have achieved this with jQuery but there are some issues:

When the user does write something into the input field, the specific information is visible. But when the user deletes his input and does write something else, the "old" info is still there and the "new" info just appends. The old info should be hidden and the new one should replace it.

Here is a `<a href="https://jsfiddle.net/szb8wbaq/5/">JSFiddle</a>.`

How can I achieve this?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap the content you want to show in a span with an ID (like span id="contenttoshow"), and check whether it exists before outputting your results. If it does exist, then remove() it (https://api.jquery.com/remove/), and then append the new content.

Checking it could be like

```
if ( $( "#contenttoshow" ).length > 0 ) {
    $( "#contenttoshow" ).remove();
}
```

Comment: If you want to "pimp it", then you can add fadeOut( callback ), and only remove() in the callback - then the old content would gradually disappear, and not just vanish in an instant. Anyways, I'm happy that I could help :)